# type object callback with default arguments

Tags: typescript

In a javascript library, I need to set my callback functions in an object. I want to also be able to use default parameters in the arguments of the callback function that is stored in the typescript object. It's going to look similar to this...

```
type Info = {
  setStatus: (newStatus: string | null) => void;
};

let status: string | null = null;

const info: Info = {
  setStatus: (newStatus: string | null = null) => {
    status = newStatus;
  }
};

info.setStatus();
```

We can see typescript is complaining that it is expecting an argument in:

`info.setStatus();` <----- expects argument

`Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.`

`An argument for 'newStatus' was not provided.`

[image]

even though we are utilizing a default parameter in our callback function.

How do I let typescript know in the type to use a default parameter in the argument of the callback function?

Comment: You annotated `info` as `Info` which knows of no such default.  Do you want `Info` to allow for a missing argument? Then do [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1aMYw).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Info` type, you need to make the parameter [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) in order to allow the method to be called without any parameters. As far as I know, you can't *enforce* that an implementation would use `null` as a default value in that situation, but it *allows* one to:

```typescript
type Info = {
    setStatus: (newStatus?: string | null) => void;
    //                   ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− here
};

let status: string | null = null;

const info: Info = {
    setStatus: (newStatus: string | null = null) => {
        status = newStatus;
    }
};

info.setStatus();
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL5wPSrgFQBYEsDOcBc2wUwcMElwANrZaXGLQIYCeA5lBAK4B2AE0bFirOAFsIg3rWAAaOPmoADfDFYxe+FUXz8A5PBhMARr1y0YAWlz84g4GHIBjTcGGdaEU61oAofxh2MAoASX4AM2oAXkR-OESlYBgAZQ0tfAAuOAAKfmAAd3TNbQB+HPUoO044AB84fllaAEo4GIA+OAA3CFxBAG5-JCH-OXh1UuylGGr+Woam+nbG5tGXCH51IiiIHIjolYQEpPwUksyc-KKL7UrZmvrV5bil1vau46TvmamVguKGW0Q2+SGGozs0QAdGc0kD8LkWgMgA)